# Double variable if statement not working

Tags: python, variables, if-statement, double, inequalities

I'm making a double variable if statement and it keeps returning an error. I don't know what's wrong:

```
variable = float(0)

for index in range(10):

    variable = variable + float(2)

    if x <= float(variable/3) and > float(variable-2.0/3):
        # do something

    else:
        pass
```

or something like that. This is the basic structure. Why does it keep highlighting the > in red whenever I try to run it?

Comment: I don't know what language this is in. You should add it as a tag.

Comment: Wild guess as I don't even recognize the language this is, but shouldn't there be some variable name just before the `>` ?  And maybe some () to make things a lot more readable?

Answer (score 6):

Python supports regular inequalities as well, so you could just write this:

```
if variable - 2.0 / 3 < x <= variable / 3:
    # ...
```

Answer (score 2):

You want to do something like

```
if ((x <= float(variable/3)) and (x > float(variable-2.0/3))):
       # do something

 else:
       pass
```

In other words, each side of the and must be a boolean expression on its own.  I'm not sure whether you need all the parenthesis.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you're missing a variable or constant before the second condition in the if-block. That might be one reason you're getting an error.

Answer (score 0):

This code works fine:

```
index=0
```

`x=0`

`variable = float(0)`

`for index in range(10):`
    
`variable=variable + float(2)`

```
if x <= float(variable/3) and x> float(variable-2.0/3):
    print 'Doesn\'t Matter'
else:
    print 'pass'
```